# 'FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.h' file not found

Tags: xcode, swift, fbsdk

I was using FBSDKLoginKit without any problem until morning.

I imported FBSDKLogin kit using cocoapod :

```
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'LePhoceen' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for LePhoceen
  pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'
  pod 'GoogleMobileAds'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 1.3.0'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.3'
  pod 'TwitterKit'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.7'
  pod 'ATInternet-iOS-Swift-SDK', '~> 2.2'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBAudienceNetwork'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9.2'
end
```

and I created a bridge :

```
#import <Google/Analytics.h>
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h>
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

But now when I import 'FBSDKLoginKit' I get the error

> /Users/maxmargheriti/Desktop/LePhocéen/LePhoceeniOS/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h:23:9: 'FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginManager.h' file not found
>    and 
>   /Users/maxmargheriti/Desktop/LePhocéen/LePhoceeniOS/LePhoceen/Views/Login/LoginVC.swift:13:8: Could not build Objective-C module 'FBSDKLoginKit'

Thanks for your help !

Comment: try adding #import <FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h> to your bridging

Comment: if I add this import i get the following error : /Users/maxmargheriti/Desktop/LePhocéen/LePhoceeniOS/LePhoceen/LePhoceen-Bridging-Header.h:9:9: 'FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.h' file not found